# C# Override an Event in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, events, overriding

I need to add an Event for all my Textboxes in a C# winforms app.

How can I override for example, the `Enter` event so all textboxes will have by default this event ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what you want it a custom textbox that inherits from `TextBox`.  Do you special event things in that class.  Then just use that textbox everywhere

Comment: Derive your own class from TextBox.  Override OnEnter().  Build and drop it from the top of the toolbox.

Comment: Do you have to do this in WinForms, this is actually not terribly hard to do in WPF using [`EventManager.RegisterClassHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597875(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, the problem that i'm using Telerik winforms but when i've entered the the designer.cs , i've been able to use my custom Textbox event.

Answer (score 3):

You can inherit `YourTextBox` from `TextBox` and override `OnEnter` method to provide default behavior for all such textboxes. Then use this control instead of default `TextBox` controls:

```
public class YourTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        // do something here
        base.OnEnter(e);
    }
}
```

Or you can subscribe all textboxes to same event handler. You can do that either manually, or programmatically. E.g. if you are interested only in top-level textboxes of Form:

```
foreach (var textBox in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
     textBox.Enter += YourEventHandler;
```

Comment: Hi Sergey , 
Thank you very much i needed both solution that you provided for different uses :) , this solved my issues