# Why does pressing Alt+X in a RichTextBox switch characters to a unicode/hex sometimes?

Tags: c#, winforms

Pressing **Alt+X** in a regular RichTextBox (I've tried several .NET Framework targets) can replace the text with unicode/hex characters.

To reproduce
- Start a regular .NET Winforms project.
- Drop a RichTextBox on the form
- Build > type **1234** in the RichTextBox, then press **Alt+X**.
- You should see the text now has become a unicode character (kind of looks like a helmet).
- Depending on the last several set of characters, the resulting change can differ, or not happen at all.
- Another example - type **ssss** then do Alt+X, the last s will switch to 73.

We discovered this when trying to access a Toolstrip button that had a hotkey of X (E&xit) upon completion of entering text into a RichTextBox.

What I've tried:
- Several fonts
- Setting the ShortCutsEnabled property to false

My tentative solution is to use the KeyPress event, and if they press Alt and X, set e.Handled to true.  Kind of a hack though.

Anyone have any better ideas or answer to why this is happening? :)

Comment: I'm assuming by "a regular .NET Windows App project" you mean a WinForm. If you want to prevent the default event, you can override it. You can do this with specific controls too (as opposed to overriding the event for every control of that type). As far as it feeling 'hacky', I think that's a pretty standard approach to the problem. You're just adding custom logic to the event, otherwise, you'd have to jump through tons of hoops, and it'd probably end up being messier.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43668106/c-sharp-override-an-event-in-winforms

Comment: It is a [documented feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-rich-edit-controls#rich-edit-shortcut-keys).  Use KeyDown to prevent the control from seeing it, not a hack.

Comment: Thank you Hans!  Simple explanation of why - it's a documented feature. :)


Dortimer -  Based on your feedback, I added Winforms to the tags and replaced the "regular .NET Windows App project" with .NET Winforms project.


Thanks again to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

As Hans mentioned this is intended behavior. If you wish to disable this feature you may override KeyDown and mark this particular event as handled.

Note that the keystrokes will come in separately, so it's a little tricky to maintain the state -- something like this should work:

```
bool AltKeyPressed = false;
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (AltKeyPressed)
  {
    AltKeyPressed = false;
    if (e.SystemKey == Key.X) {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
   }

  if (e.SystemKey == Key.LeftAlt || e.SystemKey == Key.RightAlt)
  {
    AltKeyPressed = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not necessary, just test for e.KeyData == (Keys.X | Keys.Alt)

Comment: Wouldn't this also trigger if the user pressed Alt and X _consecutively_ (as opposed to in combination)?